# Feature Request - Highlighting texts instead of commenting +1

Tags: feature-request, comments, upvotes

There are many comments under answers that are in the form of

> +1 "This is the main point"

Users post comments like this to highlight a key reason why they decided to give the answer an upvote.

Why not make it more like an e-reader where the text of the question itself can be highlighted and show how many people highlighted it?

This would show what the community has determined is the key point or reason why the question got at upvote.

For example:

> Question:
>
> Why does foo bar?
>
> Answer:
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud **exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip** *[314 users highleted this as reason to upvote]* ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
>   aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
>   dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
>   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
>   laborum.

This raises some obvious questions:

- What reputation should be required to allow highlighting? We don't want hordes of low rep users highlighting what they think is the expert answer...
- Should this be able to be toggled on an off? Just like an e-reader? Highlights could be distracting when reading content in an answer. How would toggling work?

Comment: + 1 "highlight a key reason why they decided to give the answer an upvote" :P

Comment: Personally, that sounds like it could get a little distracting. There is already adequate tools for highlighting pieces of an answer that are the ***most important***. This is usually done by the author himself but posts can be edited by others, as well, to make the most important parts stand out.

Comment: This could be kinda cool for longer answers, though I think we'd want to not show highlighting by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. For several reasons.

First, I do not believe that this is a problem worth solving. Maybe it's just the tags I look in, but I very rarely see comments of the form `+1 "Direct Quote From The Text"`. Nor do I see `"Direct Quote From The Text" +1`. Oh sure, it happens. But this is not exactly a plague on the site.

Second, the last thing I want to see are my posts being damaged by random highlighting from whoever wants to add highlighting. It's one thing for someone to edit your posts to add highlighting. It's quite another when they can just do it, with no recourse from anyone.

You should not be able to affect the look of a post without modifying it.

Third, adding such highlighting would *normalize* the desire for people to thumbs-up a specific subsection of a post. That is, it would say that this is a thing we want people to do. I don't see why we should want that. We have upvote and downvote buttons for the post itself. That's good enough. At least with comments of the form you describe, you can always flag them to get rid of the pointless noise.